# RhodeCode - What is blocking my connection?

Tags: centos, rhodecode

All connection attempts on RhodeCode on CentOS 6.3 are refused except from localhost.

Note that `iptables` is not running, and I am only trying to visit the web interface.

I have googled the exact error message below and looked around SO. I have yet to find a solution.

`abort: error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

If the firewall is down, and I am not trying to modify any repository, what else is preventing me from connecting? **EDIT:** See #5 below. Not sure how to address it yet.

**Things tried and other info**

1. Using localhost, 127.0.0.1 and hostname in `production.ini`
2. `service iptables stop`
3. Connected over HTTP successfully. In other words, connections are accepted outside RhodeCode.
4. Made sure no authentication methods were enabled or configured in `production.ini`
5. Although the server accepts connections on localhost, `netstat -l` does not show that port 5000 is listening. Port 5000 is set in `production.ini` and `ps uax | grep paster` confirms the server is running. No other software tries to grab port 5000.

Comment: I have same issue on ubuntu server 12.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, apparently I have been misunderstanding the `host` configuration. I was running on the assumption that `host` should be set to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` in production.ini for RhodeCode to know what host to look for for another service. This was a faulty presumption on my part, since I am used to pointing web applications to local systems to look for databases.

It turns out that `host` binds the application to a specific address for access, meaning that it RhodeCode was supposed to only respond to local requests, regardless of what other system policies say. The [setup docs did not make this clear](http://packages.python.org/RhodeCode/setup.html) because it did not specify that external connections would be refused. All it said was:

> This command [paster serve] runs the RhodeCode server. The web app should be available at the 127.0.0.1:5000. This ip and port is configurable via the production.ini file created in previous step

The problem was fixed by binding RhodeCode to `0.0.0.0`, which opened it to outside connections. Kudos to Łukasz Balcerzak for [pointing this out](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rhodecode/_EyNX2jzAZg/6lQTvTsdqJcJ) in the RC support google group.